# How do we prove intuitionistically that free modules of finite rank are projective?

Tags: commutative-algebra, projective-module, constructive-mathematics

I'm struggling to understand how the following proof can be intuitionistically valid$^1$:

> **Theorem.** Let $R$ be a commutative ring. A free module of finite rank $R^n$ is projective.
>
> *Proof*. Let $A \overset{g}\to B$ be an onto map of modules, let $R^n \overset{f}\to B$ be a map of modules. Let moreover $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ be a basis of $R^n$. Then there exist $a_1, \ldots, a_n \in A$ such that $g(a_i) = f(x_i)$ for $i=1,\ldots,n$. By universal property of the free modules then, the map $x_i \mapsto a_i$ can be extended to the desired map of modules $R^n \overset{h}\to A$.

This is the standard proof, and it is given in a constructive context e.g. in [MRR, p. 57].

However it seems to me that to choose elements $a_1, \ldots, a_n$ we must employ some kind of choice principle. Is this true?

---

1. This mean it doesn't lean on LEM (law of excluded middle, i.e. no arguing by contradiction), AC (axiom of choice), DC ([axiom of dependent choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_dependent_choice)), AC$_\omega$ ([axiom of countable choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_countable_choice)).

---

[MRR] Mines, Richman, Ruitenburg; *A course in constructive algebra*, Springer-Verlag, 1988.

Comment: Sure thing@rschwieb! I've edited my answer.

Comment: If you are not allowed to choose one element from each of a set of finitely many sets,  I'm not sure what kind of mathematics you would be doing.  Certainly not anything fun!  If that is in doubt, then apparently you cannot even say "let $x$ be an element of $A$" given a set $A$.

Comment: @mattecapu: making finitely many choices amounts to claiming that the cartesian product of finitely many nonempty sets is itself nonempty, claim which is easily provable by induction (on the number of factors involved in the cartesian product). The proof for the induction step will require justifying the analogous statement for just one set, in other words the claim that given a nonempty set it will have an element! In this case, an element of a nonempty set can always be introduced by existential dequantification.

Comment: @mattecapu Furthermore, the above claim is actually valid for **arbitrary free modules over arbitrary rings** (not necessarily commutative), although for people who only allow themselves to be persuaded by constructivist-empiricist type arguments this might be a hard to accept fact.

Comment: @ΑΘΩ: "empiricism" is a philosophical concept that I don't believe is relevant here. You should understand that there are many people who don't find non-constructive proofs unconvincing, but often find constructive proofs more informative and hence more useful. In the case in point, the argument for arbitrary free modules over arbitrary rings has essentially the same computational content as the argument for the finitely generated commutative case, so I really don't see what you are getting at.

Comment: Getting back to the question, a constructive proof that a function $g: A \to B$ is onto provides an algorithm for a function $f$ that maps each $b \in B$ to an $a \in A$ such that $f(a) = b$. So no "choice principle" is needed: the algorithm to make the choices you need is a given.

Comment: Thanks Rob, that's exactly what I wasn't seeing. In hindsight it looks very obvious indeed.

Comment: @RobArthan does also this imply the hypothesis of finite rank is superfluous?

Comment: I think that depends on whether you want to interpret $R^n$ as an iterated product or an iterated sum if $n$ is infinite.

Comment: It should be a product. Why is it so however?

Comment: @RobArthan: Indeed it is, I was only using the term in a loose sense (perhaps quite too loose). Of the other point I am also aware, not trying to paint a picture in which the majority of people with mathematical preoccupations can only be convinced by constructive proofs. And with the further remark that, whenever possible, taking a constructive-prescriptive approach is more informative, with that remark I also agree. If anything, I was alluding to people who might treat infinite choices as no longer constructivist (or not as constructivist as finitary ones) and thus not so persuasive.

Comment: @Rob Arthan: so may I at least partly take back my previous comment.

Comment: @ΑΘΩ: thanks for clarifying your comment. My comment too was a bit mixed: my main point was inspired my belief (and hope) that an increasing number of mathematicians embrace both the classical and the constructive poinst of view as contrasting approaches with their own individual merits and demerits.

Comment: Actually, I think you have to interpret $R^n$ as a sum rather than a product to make the result true if $n$ is infinite: the free $R$-module generated by a set $X$ is the sum $\sum_{i \in X}R$: i.e., the set of sequences $(x_1, x_2, \ldots)$ of elements of $R$ such that $x_i = 0$ for all but finitely many $i$. I think a good constructive representation of the elements of $\sum_{i \in \Bbb{N}}R$ has to include both the function $i \mapsto x_i$ and a bound on the $i$ such that $x_i \neq 0$.

Comment: @Rob Arthan: you are most right about signaling that $A^I$ for infinite $I$ (I prefer to denote my rings by $A, B, C$ rather than $R, S..$) is no longer free in general (it fails to be so even for $A$ a PID not a field and $I=\mathbb{N}$).

Comment: The free algebra functor is given by $FS=\mathrm{colim}_{T\in\mathrm{Fin}\,S}(F(1)\cdot T)$, the filtered colimit with respect to finite subsets of $S$ of copowers of the free object over the singleton $F(1)$. So it's a colimit, so colimit notation is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So to answer my question, the proof is valid since:

1. As Rob Arthan pointed out, we can extract the elements $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ from a proof of surjectivity of $g$ (which, intuitionistically, explicitly describes how to find at least one preimage for each element of $B$).
2. As rschwieb remarked, since we only make finitely many choices there's no need of any strong choice principle.

Answer (score 1):

It might be helpful to reframe the theorem more generally.

Let $\mathcal{S}$ be a regular category, and let $\mathcal{T}$ be the category of models of a finitary algebraic theory. Let $F\dashv G:\mathcal{T}\to\mathcal{S}$ be the free-forgetful adjunction ($G$ preserves covers because $S$ is regular). Then $FS$ is projective in $\mathcal{T}$ whenever $S$ is projective in $\mathcal{S}$.

For given cover $g:A\to B$ and morphism $f:FS \to B$, consider the diagram with the adjunct $f' : S\to GB$ and $Gg : GA \to GB $. Then $Gg$ is a cover, so from $S$ being projective we get a map $h :S \to GA $ that "completes the triangle". Taking adjuncts again gets us $f=gh'$ for some $h' :FS \to A$.

---

Then the additional ingredient needed is that finite sets are projective. That's a theorem once you've chosen the correct notion of "finite set".